# Merging Html with Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, pulp

So basically I have the following code which produces a map of a country with its districts and each time I click one district it appears a pop up and I have a code for a calculator pretty much that requires the user to input two values Demand and Investment. What I wanted to do is ask the user those two values each time he clicks on district on the map.

```
def create_map():
    folder_path = r'D:\Trabalho de Licenciatura\New folder\Python\Moz Geo Data\Distritos'
    shapefile_path = folder_path + "\Distritos.shp"
    districts = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)
    
    districts_json = districts.to_crs(epsg='4326').to_json()
    
    districts_data = json.loads(districts_json)

    map_mozambique = folium.Map(location=[-18.665695, 35.529562], zoom_start=6)

    def generate_popup_content(properties):
        html = f"<h3>{properties['ADM2_PT']}</h3>"
        html += f"<p>Additional information: {properties['ADM1_PT']}</p>"
        return folium.Popup(html)

    for feature in districts_data['features']:
        properties = feature['properties']
        geometry = feature['geometry']
        popup_content = generate_popup_content(properties)
        folium.GeoJson(
            data=geometry,
            style_function=lambda x: {
                'fillColor': '#ffff00',
                'color': '#000000',
                'weight': 1,
                'fillOpacity': 0.4
            },
            highlight_function=lambda x: {'weight': 3},
            tooltip=properties['ADM2_PT'],
            popup=popup_content
        ).add_to(map_mozambique)

    map_mozambique.save('mapa.html')
    webbrowser.open('mapa.html')

create_map()
```

#And

```
def lp(district_name):
    import pulp
    
    model = pulp.LpProblem(name="Lp", sense=pulp.const.LpMinimize)
    A=float(consts(district_name).get("A"))
    B=float(consts(district_name).get("B"))
    C=float(consts(district_name).get("C"))
    x_1 = pulp.LpVariable(name="x_1", lowBound=0)
    x_2 = pulp.LpVariable(name="x_2", lowBound=0)
    x_3 = pulp.LpVariable(name="x_3", lowBound=0)
    
    obj_func = 41*x_1 + 11*x_2 + 24*x_3
    
    model += obj_func
    
    
    model += (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 >= float(input("Demand?")))
    model += (A*x_1 + B*x_2 + C*x_3 <= float(input("Investment?")) )
    
    
    status = model.solve()
    for var in model.variables():
        
        print(f"{var.name}:{var.value()}")

def consts(district):
    import openpyxl
    values={}
    book= openpyxl.load_workbook(r"D:\Trabalho de Licenciatura\New folder\Python\WebApp\Dados_py.xlsx")
    worksheet=book["Dados"]
    
    for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, values_only=True):
        if row[0]==district:
            value_A=str(row[1])
            value_B=str(row[2])
            value_C=str(row[3])
            values={"A": value_A, "B": value_B, "C": value_C}
    
    return values

lp()
```

I tried using Flask and also use some javascripts to achieve what I wanted but for some reason none of the Javascript code was running.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your question... it's a bit difficult for people to help you when you're not showing the full code and what error you are getting. Try to rephrase your question to point exactly to what is the problem, or what advice you are looking for.

Comment: I basically wanted to know a good approach to solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to setup a backend server, and then serve some HTML pages.

Folium is a python framework that can display maps but it is not interactive beyond pan/zoom.

For a more interactive interface in a purely Python environment, you might want to look at some other python UI framework like

- Streamlit that has a map widget https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/charts/st.map
  or
- Gradio https://gradio.app/ https://gradio.app/plot-component-for-maps/

but if you're looking to build a real web app, learn about Flask or FastAPI for the back end, and learn Javascript (like React, Vue or Angular) for the front end.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to use Flask and the map html file generated as a base for the web app and maybe try to add some info in the pop up generated with folium and a link to another HTML file where the user is prompted to insert the necessary values for the calculator to work and the result is shown also in that page since it seems that I cannot do much just with the map generated with folium.